how to record audio without it being in the application/octet-stream format, preferably ogg or mp3 in react ts
I'm trying to record audio in my react application with typescript using the MediaRecorder lib as you can see in the code below, and trying to send this file to the WhatsappBusinessCloudApi api but it's returning the following error:
{
code: 131053,
title: 'Audio file uploaded with mimetype as audio/ogg; codecs=opus, however on processing it is of type application/octet-stream. Please choose a different file.'
}
Here my code:

    const startRecording = async () => {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
        var options = {
            audioBitsPerSecond: 42666,
            mimeType: 'audio/webm; codecs=opus',
        };
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
        mediaRecorderRef.current = mediaRecorder;

        mediaRecorder.start();
        setIsRecording(true);
        setRecordingTime(0);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            audioChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
        };

        mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
            const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunksRef.current, { type: 'audio/ogg' });
            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
            console.log(' ~ startRecording ~ audioUrl:', audioUrl);
            setAudioUrl(audioUrl);
            setFiles((prevFiles) => [...prevFiles, new File([audioBlob], 'recording.ogg', { type: 'audio/ogg' })]);
            audioChunksRef.current = [];
            clearInterval(timerRef.current!);
        };

        timerRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
            setRecordingTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
        }, 1000);
    };


can anyone help me?
